# RGB to HSI Conversion - Hue always calculated as 0

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

So I've been trying to create this RGB to HSI conversion algorithm for a project I'm working on but I have run into several roadblocks while doing it.

I've so far narrowed the problems down to two possible issues:

- The program will not detect which of the two values compared in the if-statement is true and just defaults to the initial if-statement
- The program is not calculating the correct values when calculating the hue of the image as it always defaults to the inverse cosine's default value.

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def RGB_TO_HSI(img):

with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):

    bgr = cv2.split(img)

    intensity = np.divide(bgr[0] + bgr[1] + bgr[2], 3)
    saturation = 1 - 3 * np.divide(np.minimum(bgr[2], bgr[1], bgr[0]), bgr[2] + bgr[1] + bgr[0])

    def calc_hue(bgr):
        blue = bgr[0]
        green = bgr[1]
        sqrt_calc = np.sqrt(((bgr[2] - bgr[1]) * (bgr[2] - bgr[1])) + ((bgr[2] - bgr[0]) * (bgr[1] - bgr[0])))

        if green.any >= blue.any:
            hue = np.arccos(1/2 * ((bgr[2]-bgr[1]) + (bgr[2] - bgr[0])) / sqrt_calc)
        else:
            hue = 360 - np.arccos(1/2 * ((bgr[2]-bgr[1]) + (bgr[2] - bgr[0])) / sqrt_calc)

        hue = np.int8(hue)
        return hue

    hue = calc_hue(bgr)
    hsi = cv2.merge((intensity, saturation, calc_hue(bgr)))
```

[Here is the formula I used for the conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukpFr.jpg)

Thanks in advance for any tips or ideas

Comment: I found some errors in the calculation (or at least I think it was errors) and now hue outputs NaN instead of numbers.

Comment: Why not use OpenCV's method for conversion directly?

Comment: It's for an assignment and the requirements state that I am not allowed to use OpenCV except for reading, writing and showing images. The conversion must be done by an algorithm that I've written.

Comment: hue is a value between 0 and 360, but you convert it to int8 which is -128 to +127. Could this be the problem? I don't have enough experience with python type conversion here. Can you add your used RGB-to-HSV formulas in your question?

Comment: @Micka The formula I used is attached to the original post now

Comment: probably you'll have to convert the angles to "degrees" like angle*pi/180 before using them in your 360 degrees - angle for example?

Comment: I totally forgot having the 360 stated as degrees, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok there is a lot going on here. I must say this, I know you are new, but before you post a question check the docs otherwise you'll end up using the libs wrong. (i.e. `np.minimum()` does not compare 3 values at once).

Pay attention to your variables types. Your code does operations with `np.uint8` as if they where `np.int32`. Always try to keep consistency with your variables types.

Enough said, without changing your code too much here is what I came up with:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from math import pi

def BGR_TO_HSI(img):

  with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):

    bgr = np.int32(cv2.split(img))

    blue = bgr[0]
    green = bgr[1]
    red = bgr[2]

    intensity = np.divide(blue + green + red, 3)

    minimum = np.minimum(np.minimum(red, green), blue)
    saturation = 1 - 3 * np.divide(minimum, red + green + blue)

    sqrt_calc = np.sqrt(((red - green) * (red - green)) + ((red - blue) * (green - blue)))

    if (green >= blue).any():
      hue = np.arccos((1/2 * ((red-green) + (red - blue)) / sqrt_calc))
    else:
      hue = 2*pi - np.arccos((1/2 * ((red-green) + (red - blue)) / sqrt_calc))

    hue = hue*180/pi

    hsi = cv2.merge((hue, saturation, intensity))
    return hsi
```

I hope it helped

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot! I'll read up on the docs a bit more in the future

Comment: @SimonLaursen I just Edited the answer to correct the angle of the hue, now it returns a value from 0 to 360 degrees